# Round a number using Math.Round with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to get a number from a text box and divide that number by 5.5 in another text box. The answer needs to be rounded up to the nearest whole. The problem I'm having is how do I implement the Math.Round using text boxes? Below is how I tried to get it to work.

```
double num2 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text,1,0)) / 5.5;
textBox6.Text = num2.ToString();

double num2 = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble)textBox5.Text / 5.5);

double num2 = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text,0.00(MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))) / 5.5;
textBox6.Text = num2.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break it down to a single operation per line of code and do it this way:

```
var x = Double.Parse(textBox5.Text);

x = x / 5.5;

x = Math.Round(x, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

textBox6.Text = x.ToString();
```